# Получить только 3 рандомных поста из категории

Tags: wordpress

как настроить этот цикл чтобы из категории 4 бралось только 3 последних(новых) поста?

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php  query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php  endwhile; ?>
<?php  else: ?>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на `query_posts('cat=4&orderby=id&order=ASC&show_posts=3');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=3');
```